# The text goes missing after adding <ul> tag in span

Tags: html, css

I am a new learner for Html designing email templates. I need to add text in front of a symbol and make sure the text remains aligned for the next line. I am using  tag to properly align the text after the symbol. But for some reason it doesn't seems to be working.

After adding the  tag the text is not displaying, it disappears. if i remove

the text appears again. I am not sure what is the reason for this behavior. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Browser</title>
</head>

 <div class="b opaf v" style=font-size:0;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%>
                            <table cellpadding=0 style=border:none;vertical-align:top width=100%>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align=left class=x style=font-size:0;word-break:break-word>
                                        <div style=text-align:left>
                                          <p style=margin:0;text-align:left><span style=font-size:12px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:400;color:#54565b;line-height:14px><span style=color:inherit;font-weight:inherit;font-family:inherit;font-size:65%;vertical-align:4px;line-height:0>&sect;</span><span><ul><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li></ul></span>
                                            </span>
                                           </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused by your layout.  You don't want a `<ul>` (which is a block element) inside a `<span>` (which is an inline element).

Comment: I would need the text to be aligned. As of now the text in the next line aligns below the symbol. but i want the text to be justified with the first word and not the symbol.

Comment: Is there any rule that we cannot use <ul> inside span.?

Comment: this ```style``` is causing the problem. Also you need to add quote ```" "``` every time you add attribute on your tag.

Comment: Yes, there is a rule.  You cannot put a block element inside an inline element.  https://www.codementor.io/@afuggini/block-vs-inline-elements-in-html-what-they-are-and-why-you-should-understand-them-fo7jcqwg3

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually missing.

`ul` tag is a *block level element* meaning it should do a line break. Therefore text and bullet go to next line and It is not seen because of your styles.

So, By adding this in your `<ul>` tag

```
style="margin-top:-15px;margin-left:-20px;font-size:10px;"
```

It will show the text and the bullet.

```html
<div class="b opaf v" style=font-size:0;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%>
  <table cellpadding=0 style=border:none;vertical-align:top width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td align=left class=x style=font-size:0;word-break:break-word>
          <div style=text-align:left>
            <p style=margin:0;text-align:left>
              <span style=font-size:12px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:400;color:#54565b;line-height:14px>
                <span style=color:inherit;font-weight:inherit;font-family:inherit;font-size:65%;vertical-align:4px;line-height:0>
                  &sect;
                </span>
                <span>
                  <ul style="margin-top:-15px;margin-left:-20px;font-size:10px;">
                    <li>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </span>
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```